# ¿Como hacer el login en angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular5

estoy intentado hacerlo con httpclient pero no consigo el  objetivo este es mi codigo

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {SessionStorageService} from 'ngx-webstorage';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
selector: 'app-login',
templateUrl: './login.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent  {

sesion = false;
user;


constructor(public _http:HttpClient, 
public _local:SessionStorageService,
public _rutas:Router) { 
}

login(event: Event){

const url = 'http://localhost/api/public/login';


this._http.post(url,{
'username':this.user.username,
'password':this.user.password

}).subscribe(data => {

    this.user = data;
    this.sesion = true;
    this._local.store('user',data);
    this._rutas.navigate(['/home']);

 console.log('ha ido bien');

 }, error => {

  console.log('error');
  this.sesion = false;
  });
```

}

la api le llega por post el usuario y la contraseña y te devuelve un token
si no están en la base de datos

el codigo html del formulario es el siguiente

```
 <form #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="login($event)"class="col-sm-5">
 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="username">Username</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username"  placeholder="Enter 
 Username" [(ngModel)]="user.username" #username="ngModel">

 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
 <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" 
 placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="user.password" #password="ngModel">
 </div>

 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que error te da? Has probado la API por separado (con postman)?

Comment: username of undefined me da ese error en realidad tendria que mandar el token pero no lo estoy haciendo lo quiero no se como hacerlo en el postnman si me funciona

Comment: ya lo he solucionado ya me devuelve el usuario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error esta al hacer **solamente**: `user;`

### La solución rápida:

Haz dos string, como por ejemplo:

```
let username: string = "";
let password: string = "";
```

Y en la vista: (**HTML**)
Para el usuario `[(ngModel)]="username"` y para la contraseña `[(ngModel)]="password"`.

---

### Otra opción mejor

> Es declarar la clase Usuario y utilizarla:

**Declaración de la clase:**

```
class User{
  constructor(private username:string, private password:string){
  }
}
```

**En el código:**

```
let user: User;
```

**En el HTML:**

Para el usuario `[(ngModel)]="user.username"` y para la contraseña `[(ngModel)]="user.password"`.

Comment: me sigue dando error

Comment: Y cual seria el error, el mismo? Recuerda leer [Como Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), recuerda que siempre tienes que pegar el log de error.